# Create an email address that forwards to users in role

Tags: user-roles, email

I am looking for a method that, functionally, creates a group "reflector" or **forwarding email address**, for **all the users in a custom role**.  For example, if I create the custom role "OompaLoompas", I would like a email address of OompaLoompas@mysite.com to be created, which reflects that changing user base, allowing anyone to email this user group from their email of choice- not just administrators from an admin panel.  ***How can I accomplish this?***

My reasoning is that I'm using my WordPress installation to manage subcommittees, and have been asked to create group redirectors for each subcommittee.  At this time, no one has email on mysite.com, and **I've been asked to avoid creating a new email address for every user**.

Comment: WordPress isn't a mail server. So you can have a message sent from a form to all users of a user role, but not a catch-all email for your group. At least, I've never seen anything of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Your question's answer is pretty long and it covers vast amount of tasks done. So it's kinda pretty impossible to explain the full process with code here. I'm giving you some infos and advice here. Hope that helps you.

The steps needed-

1. **User Taxonomy:** You can create user groups with giving them taxonomy based group relations like `posts` or any other post types. [Here you'll find a brief tutorial about it.](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress)
2. **Create Email Address:** Hook in create user taxonomy. That means after create user taxonomy it'll create a email address.
3. **Send Mail:** Create a form which will tak ethe email inputs form user. Then sent it to all the user associated with the taxonomy.

Comment: VERY helpful!  I've handled the taxonomy, and #3 should not be an issue-
Do you have any pointers to accomplish the hook described #2?
Thank you much.